# how to use sharepoint list data source with SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to create a SSRS report based on data provided by SharePoint List.

I am trying to connect SharePoint Data source by selecting `Microsoft SharePoint List` type in Data Source Properties window and providing connection string in format

`http://server/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/`

while configuring data set, not able to log in even after entering credentials. Is there anything i am missing or Are there any configuration need to be done on SharePoint Server?

Answer (score 0):

@Rohaan, use integrated mode. Stored credentials do not place nice with SharePoint lists.